# How to write a function that finds the mode of a list and saves it as dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need help writing a function  findMode(aList)  that accepts a list of items as a parameter, and proceeds to find the mode.  However, your Python solution must use a dictionary to keep track of the items and their counts as the method of finding the mode (not parallel lists).

Here is the code that i have already tried:

```
def findMode(aList):
    aList.sort()
    position = 0
    largestCount = 0
    listLength = len(aList)
    while(position <= listLength):
        count = aList.count(aList[position])
        if(count > largestCount):
            largestCount = count
            valuePosition = aList[position]
        position += count
    return aList[valuePosition]
```

Here are some examples of the desired outcome:

```
>>> findMode([4,3,4,3,2,1,4,5,3,3,4,5,1,4,1,4,5])
[4]
>>> findMode(["horse ", "cat ", "dog ", "turtle ","horse ", "cat ", "dog ", "turtle "])
['horse ', 'cat ', 'dog ', 'turtle ']
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```py
from collections import Counter

def findMode(aList):
    counter = Counter(aList)
    max_count = max(counter.values())
    return [item for item, count in counter.items() if count == max_count]
```

Comment: Beat me by like 30 seconds!

Comment: And me. :-) Had it in my clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def findMode(aList):
  dic_freq = {}
  for element in aList:
    if element not in aList.keys():
      dic_freq[element] = 1
    else:
      dic_freq[element] += 1

  mode = [el for el in dic_freq.keys() if dic_freq[el] == max(dic_freq.values())]
  return mode
```

You can do it faster without dictionary but it works that way

Comment: you can use `defaultdict` to avoid this `if element not in aList.keys():
      dic_freq[element] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def findMode(aList):
    dic = defaultdict(int)
    for i in aList:
        dic[i]+=1
    mv = max(dic.values())
    return [i for i in dic if dic[i]==mv]

findMode([4,3,4,3,2,1,4,5,3,3,4,5,1,4,1,4,5])
# output [4]

findMode(["horse ", "cat ", "dog ", "turtle ","horse ", "cat ", "dog ", "turtle "])
# output ['horse ', 'cat ', 'dog ', 'turtle ']
```

Comment: Your "output" for the first list doesn't seem right. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `most_common()` function from `Counter` dictionary to get the mode of a list:

```
import collections
from collections import Counter

num_count = ["horse ", "cat ", "dog ", "turtle ","horse ", "cat ", "dog ", "turtle "]  

count_dict = Counter(num_count)
out = count_dict.most_common() 
out_lst = list(map(lambda x: x[0], out))
```

**Output**

```
['horse ', 'cat ', 'dog ', 'turtle ']
```